# how to get package name using android toolchain on c++?

Tags: android, c++, sockets, toolchain, package-name

I have a process that attempts to get the package name from another process.
I am using C++ code and compiling it using Android toolchain.
I have its socket fd and ip address, however, I didn't find in the api a function that will return a string containing the package name.
I have the socket fd and the address, if it helps:

```
uid_t GetSocketID(int sockfd)
{
    int err;
    socklen_t len;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    len = sizeof(addr);
    int res = getpeername(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);

    if (res < 0)
    {
        err = errno;
        return -1;
    }

    int iSockIp = addr.sin_addr.s_addr;
    int iSockPort = ntohs(addr.sin_port);
    int iUid = -1;

    if (iSockIp == 0 || iSockPort == 0)
    {
            return -1;

    }
}
```

example taken from:
https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/libcutils/qtaguid.c

Does anybody know how can I get the package name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it in 3 steps:

- Use `netstat` to find the process from the socket
- Use `ps` to find the executable from the process information
- Search `AndroidManifest.xml` in the app's root dir to find the APK owning the executable.

Comment: It sounds simple, however can you be more specific in the commands? I couldn't find the relevant process. Thanks

Comment: A helpfull command: busybox netstat -tp | grep <Socket_Port>| busybox awk '{print $7}  should return the PID/Program name (first chars of it), for example: '10404/com.facebook.' that already helped me since I got the PID.